# Setting multiple divs by height percent to fill parent div

Tags: html, css, height

I have a parent div with a max height/width set. I was wondering if it's possible to set the two child divs to automatically adjust their height based on a percentage using just CSS?

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%:
}    

#parent {
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 600px;
}

#top {
    height: 30%;
}

#bottom {
    height: 70%;
}
```

The intended implementation of this would be for a mobile display that fills the screen height proportionally without forcing a vertical scroll.

EDIT:
I now realize that height percentages of the parent will work if you have a fixed parent height. The question still stands as to whether there is a way just using CSS to allow for a flexible height that matches the screen size. It's seems like this will not be possible only using CSS and require JS intervention.

Comment: You must set height of parent : http://jsfiddle.net/dimitardanailov/T5yg7 only with max-height doesn't work

Comment: Ah, so there is no way (without using js) to have it adjust and re-size  with out explicitly setting the height in css?

Comment: #parent must to have some value for height.

Comment: So the answer is no, there is no way to accomplish what I want without js intervention?

Comment: You can to make response, but need to use height for example : 100 %, but without js will be hard

Comment: you may want to use media queries to set the height of the parent element like `@media ( max-height: 500px ) { #parent { height: 480px; } }`  but there's nothing wrong with a bit of js

Comment: That's true. I could use media queries. But then I have to set one for every possible height, right? For example, the media query you just wrote. If the device has a height of 490 (for whatever reason, it's just an example) then it wouldn't fill the screen properly.

Comment: right. if you want it fully dynamic, `$('#parent').height( $(window).height() - 10 )` or something is simple enough

Comment: Simple enough using js, yes. I was just curious as to whether css alone could handle the scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theres nothing wrong with your code. Just adding a 100% height as well as width to the divs yields what you want.  The max-width/height doesn't force any values (leaves height/width at auto). Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/b6HVa/

```
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-witdh: 400px;
}
```

Comment: While what you say is 100% correct my question is a little different. What if my screen height falls below 600px. If I set the height of 600px scrolling will happen (which is what I don't want).

Comment: That does appear to work :) Let me try it out a bit and we'll see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing right, if anything going wrong, please show a demo. Or try to set

```
#top{max-height: 30%;}
#bottom{max-height: 70%;}
```

Or add `min-height: {some value}px;` to your div.

Comment: Min-height doesn't work for this example : http://jsfiddle.net/dimitardanailov/T5yg7/1/

Comment: As in your comment you are interesting without seeting height to your parent div, so I have placed min-height, but you need also to set min-height to your child divs. Hence it is recommended to you to set height in your parent div.